# After referencing an element in a WebOb.params (UnicodeMultiDict) an element gets popped off the end

Tags: python, wsgi, webob

When I reference the params parameter of the WebOb Request an element is suddenly popped off the end. That or it's being reduced to a single element. The referenced element isn't the one getting knocked off.

```
if req.str_params.has_key('method'):
   req.method = req.str_params.getone('method')
```

Before this line logging turns up:

```
DEBUG:root:NestedMultiDict([('method', 'put'), ('name', 'some_name')])
```

after:

```
DEBUG:root:NestedMultiDict([('method', 'put')])
```

I'm at a loss.

Comment: Works fine if I copy req.params to another var then use that later on, but this seems super silly.

Comment: Very odd, then -- that's only creating another reference to the same object, not making a deep copy

Comment: Right, I don't understand it. Something hinky is afoot.

Comment: Check the way it's being logged -- I looked in the source for NestedMultiDict and `getone` really shouldn't cause any modifications such as this. Write a unit test and see if you can reproduce it there -- if not, it's likely a subtlety of your own code causing this bug

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are setting `req.method`.  Probably `name=some_name` is in the *body* of the request, and so long as `req.method == 'POST'` you'll get that parameter back.  The moment you change the method to PUT you're keeping WebOb from parsing the request body (request bodies are expected to be entities, not HTML form inputs).  This is calculated when you get the attribute `req.str_params`, so by saving a reference to the params you are avoiding the req.method check.